# Как исправить резкое появление блока в javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation, ecmascript-6

Div резко появляется (свойство transition не отрабатывается).
Свойство visibility не очень нравится(т.к только скрывает элемент).
Делать opcaity `setTimeout(()=> {
  hidden_picture.style.opacity=1;

},0);` - по мне тоже не очень.

```js
document.getElementById("block").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    hidden_picture.style.display="block";
    hidden_picture.style.opacity="1"; 
    hidden_picture.style.opacity=1;  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#hidden_picture {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(47,90,128,0.3);
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
#block {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #8FACC5;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="hidden_picture"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: Не надо один и тот же вопрос задавать несколько раз.

Comment: display: none невозможно присвоить transition. Вам нужно играть с opacity, visibility, max-height, наконец

Answer (score -1):

Блоку с `display:none` невозможно присвоить `transition`.  Попробуйте скрывать блок с помощью других свойств или анимируйте изменение прозрачности с помощью `jQuery` метода `animate`

Comment: Ответ бы отмнчен тревогой, как низкого качества, я не стал рекомендовать на удаление, по сути ответ правильный, но в будущем рекомендую давать более развернуй ответы....